# Jqgrid freezes on multi user

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I have been using Jqgrid to make an application for multi user ( more than 70 persons ).The grid works perfectly on localhost and even on the server when only one person is using it but as long as there are several person logged on, the application stop loading randomly for everyone except one person. The situation comes back to normal when the one person has finish his action and the other one reload the page. 
Here is my code : 
I have looked everywhere but it seems I'm the only one to have this problem.
Thanks in advance.

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: 'include/configacompte.php', 
    editurl:"include/editacompte.php",
    datatype: "xml",
   mtype: "GET",
   postData:{idagenceco: "<?php echo $_SESSION['idAgence'] ?>" },
   colnames : [...]
    pager: jQuery("#pager"),
    rowNum: 100,
    rowList: [100, 200, 300],
    autowidth: true,
    sortname: "numSemaine",
    sortorder: "asc",
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,
     onSelectRow: function(id){
    if(id && id!==lastsel2){
        $('#list').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel2);
        $('#list').jqGrid('editRow',id,true,'','','','',reload);
        lastsel2=id;

            }
},
    multiboxonly:true,
    multiselect: true,
    loadonce : true, 
    scroll:1,
    height:500,
    ignoreCase:true,
    caption: "Gestion des Acomptes"        

});

 function reload() {
  window.location.reload();
};


$("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOperators : true,searchOnEnter:true});

$("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','url');



$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:false,add:false,refresh:false},
                {/* reloadAfterSubmit: true, closeAfterAdd: true, closeAfterEdit: true, closeAfterSubmit: true*/ }, // default settings for edit
                {/*closeAfterAdd: true*/ }, // default settings for add
                { url: 'include/editacompte.php',
                     onclickSubmit: function (options, postdata) {
                    alert('Enregistrement(s) supprimé(s)');
                    return { myData: 'Hello'};
                }
                }, // delete instead that del:false we need this
                {seOnEscape: true, closeAfterSearch: true}, // search options
                {} /* view parameters*/
               );




$("#list").jqGrid('inlineNav',"#pager",{addParams: {
    useDefValues: true,
    position :"first",
    addRowParams:{keys:true,aftersavefunc:reload}
    }},
{},// edit  
{}//add
);



$("#list").jqGrid('sortableRows');



});
```

configacompte.php

```
<?php 

//include the information needed for the connection to MySQL data base server. 
// we store here username, database and password 
include("dbconfig.php");
//include("phptest.php");

// to the url parameter are added 4 parameters as described in colModel
// we should get these parameters to construct the needed query
// Since we specify in the options of the grid that we will use a GET method 
// we should use the appropriate command to obtain the parameters. 
// In our case this is $_GET. If we specify that we want to use post 
// we should use $_POST. Maybe the better way is to use $_REQUEST, which
// contain both the GET and POST variables. For more information refer to php         documentation.
// Get the requested page. By default grid sets this to 1. 

$page = $_GET['page']; 

// get how many rows we want to have into the grid - rowNum parameter in the grid 
$limit = $_GET['rows']; 
//$limit = isset($_POST['rows'])? $_POST['rows']:100; 
// get index row - i.e. user click to sort. At first time sortname parameter -
// after that the index from colModel 
$sidx =$_GET['sidx']; //$_REQUEST['sidx']; 

// sorting order - at first time sortorder 
$sord = $_GET['sord']; // $_GET['sord']; 
//$idagenceco = $_GET['idagenceco'];*/

$idagenceco=$_GET['idagenceco'];
// if we not pass at first time index use the first column for the index or what you want
if(!$sidx) $sidx =1; 


// connect to the MySQL database server 
$db = mysql_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASSWD) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error()); 

// select the database 
 mysql_select_db(DBNAME) or die("Error connecting to db."); 

// calculate the number of rows for the query. We need this for paging the result 


$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM gestionacompte where   idAgence=$idagenceco ORDER BY IdAcompte"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC) or die(mysql_error()); 
$count = $row['count']; 


// calculate the total pages for the query 
 if( $count > 0) { 
          $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit); 
} else { 
            $total_pages = 0; 
} 

// if for some reasons the requested page is greater than the total 
// set the requested page to total page 
if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;

// calculate the starting position of the rows 
 $start = $limit*$page - $limit;

// if for some reasons start position is negative set it to 0 
// typical case is that the user type 0 for the requested page 
 if($start <0) $start = 0; 

// the actual query for the grid data 
$SQL = "SELECT IdAcompte, numAgence, nomAcompte, prenomAcompte, numSemaine, societe, montantAcompte, typeReglement, dateAcompte, idAgence FROM gestionacompte where idAgence=$idagenceco ORDER BY $sidx"; 
$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysql_error()); 


// we should set the appropriate header information. Do not forget this.
header("Content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8");

$s = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
$s .=  "<rows>";
$s .= "<page>".$page."</page>";
$s .= "<total>".$total_pages."</total>";
$s .= "<records>".$count."</records>";


// be sure to put text data in CDATA
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$s .= "<row id='". $row['IdAcompte']."'>";  
$s .= "<cell>". $row['IdAcompte']."</cell>";
$s .= "<cell>". $row['numSemaine']."</cell>";
$s .= "<cell>". $row['numAgence']."</cell>";
$s .= "<cell>". $row['nomAcompte']."</cell>";
$s .= "<cell>". $row['prenomAcompte']."</cell>";
$s .= "<cell>". $row['societe']."</cell>";
$s .= "<cell>". $row['montantAcompte']."</cell>";
$s .= "<cell>". $row['typeReglement']."</cell>";
$s .= "<cell>". $row['dateAcompte']."</cell>";
$s .= "<cell>". $row['idAgence']."</cell>";
$s .= "</row>";
}
$s .= "</rows>"; 

echo $s;

?>
```

Comment: i don't have knowledge of php. but just want to make sure that url `url: 'include/configacompte.php'` is working fine for multiple users when deployed on server.

Comment: I have edited my post with the code of configacompte.php. How can I know if it's working or not on multiple user ? I don't see why it wouldn't work. Thanks for you reply anyway it's still giving me somewhere to look.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure it caused by this >>

```
onSelectRow: function(id){
    if(id && id!==lastsel2){
        $('#list').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel2);
        $('#list').jqGrid('editRow',id,true,'','','','',reload);
        lastsel2=id;

            }
}
```

and by inlineEditing it-self .

I suggest you to use cellEditing.

Comment: I'll try to look into this too. Thanks